# sorting collection in alphabetical order in laravel

Tags: laravel, sorting, collections

I want to sort two `laravel` collection after merging them in alphabetical order, I've used the following code:

```
$result = $commonTitles->merge($newTitles)->sort();
```

And the result is sorted A to Z and then a to z.

```
["Ask","Black","Unit","ab","live","test"]
```

The result that I expect is sorting as A a to z Z. How can I change the result?

Comment: Did you already try one of the [sort flags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```php
$result = $commonTitles->merge($newTitles)->sort(SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
```